# Can I convert my .lyr file to .shp file in trial version of ArcGis Desktop 10.1?

Tags: arcgis, shapefile, qgis

I have a trial version of ArcGis Desktop 10.1. How convert my .lyr file to .shp file in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ArcGIS ArcCatalog:

Go to Table of Contents, right click on .lyr, go to DATA and select Export TO option...Here you can save it in a .shp format.

If you are using ArcGIS ArcMap:

If you can load the layer file in ArcMap and the data is accessible, you should be able to right click on the layer in the Table of Contents and export as shapefile. Below image will help you:

[image]

Click on 'Export Data' and you will see this dialog box. Click on the button highlighted in the image below

[image]

You will now see another dialog box and you can choose 'Shape File' from the drop down menu as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: Dear azmuhak,thanks for replying, but its not working. I have 60 days trial version of ArcGis 10.1.  In ArcCatalog when I right click on my .lyr file ,I get following options:copy, delete, rename, properties. In ArcMap I get the following options on right click:copy, remove, zoomToLayer, visible scale range,data,save As Layer File, Properties.

Comment: What is not working? Can you list down what issue you are having while following what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: In ArcCatalog when I right click on my .lyr file ,I get following options:copy, delete, rename, properties. In ArcMap I get the following options on right click:copy, remove, zoomToLayer, visible scale range,data,save As Layer File, Properties.

Comment: I have following extensions:3D Analyst,Geostatistical Analyst,Network Analyst, Publisher,Schematics,Spatial Analyst,Tracking Analyst

Comment: Donot right click on the layer file itself. choose a particular sublayer of points, polygons and polylines one by one to save each as a shape file. Added an image in my answer which will help you.

Comment: Thanks again, but it did not help me.Actually I had created a topology which shows errors in road network.It does not contain any sub layer.When I right click on it,then it asks me to save in .lyr format. If you can provide me your mail id then I will send you the sanp shot of it.Here i do not have permission to post snap shot. Please help.

Comment: Even when I go to File->export, there is no option to save as shape file :(

Comment: When you go to file export you can use the drop down menu near the bottom of the dialong box. There is an option of shape file in the drop down menu

Comment: Dear I have tried that then only asking question.Formats available are:EMF,EPS,AL,PDF,SVG,BMP,JPG,PNG,TIFF,GIF. You can help me by providing your mail id where I can send you snap shots. Repeating again:"I am using 60 days trial version, so was doubtful whether arc allows this functionality in trial version"

Comment: Please check my answer as I have added new images to help you. I am sorry but I do not give out my personal email on forums. Also another suggestion, we are not paid to do this work on stack overflow and it is pretty demotivating to my effort when you check and then uncheck the answer mark for my answer.

Comment: I am so sorry, by mistake I unchecked it :-) thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Your answer is perfect, but when I right click on layer and go to Data->then I get only one option "View Item Description". I think this functionality is not provided in trial version of ArcGis. Atleaset dont give -1 for this question.

Comment: I never gave -1 to you. Why would I do that

Comment: Infact gave you an upvote so that -1 is negated. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks dude, I have asked one more question regarding WebGl,if possible then answer that also.